# Laravel 8 publish apis for third parties

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, authorization

I want to build some APIs for third parties, Basically what I need is that a third party must get a token in order to access some APIs (Register User, Update User Profile), So those APIs cannot be consumed unless that third party has some token which should be valid for a limited amount of time, Once the third party has it, He can call Register User API for example.

Can you help, please?

Thanks.

Comment: For your case, I highly recommend you Laravel Passport: A first-party package that provides you with a full oauth2 server that will make all that really easy. Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/master/passport) of the documentation.

Comment: Laravel Passport is like a full oauth 2 server. Pls also checkout Laravel Sanctum if you want something much simpler: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Answer (score 0):

There are the 3 packages that can help you handle authorization:

- Laravel Sanctum (Recommend)
- Laravel JWT
- Laravel Passport

Comment: A small introduction or explanation of each one would perhaps be helpful to other users